Acts Chronological Timeline
Where can I find an accurate chronological timeline that includes the events of the Book of Acts, Paul's letters, and (also it would be nice) connections with Classical Roman history? I see many online that differ. It seems quite difficult to find a single good resource for this. I know that some events in Acts can be dated to within 1-2 years of surety (like Acts 18, since Gallio's tenure was in 51-2 A.D.). I'm looking for a scholarly resource that connects these kinds of dots if possible.
I'm following the scheme suggested by Andrew Steinmann that Jesus was born in late 3 B.C. (Herod dying in 1 B.C.), Jesus beginning his ministry in 29-30 A.D., and being crucified in 33 A.D. (Reference: https://www.academia.edu/39731184/Elapsed_Times_for_Herod_the_Great_in_Josephus). This is corroborated by Michael Heiser (https://drmsh.com/september-11-happy-birthday-to-jesus/), and Irenaeus and Tertullian (who give the nativity date in the 41st year of Augustus).
I hope follow-up on this post will be helpful for anyone else interested in the chronology/timeline of Acts.
Thank you!

Competent scholars do differ greatly on this question, so an accurate timeline is in the eye of the beholder. Steinmann has strong credentials but other good scholars will not agree with him in every respect.  (btw... because this site deals with specific biblical verses, your question might be better asked on Christianity.SE. Here you might want to ask about specific events in the Book of Acts.)

I like The MacArthur Bible Handbook as a first pass. It includes his dates on the NT books, a timeline with activities of the early church (for Acts), a timeline on the 1st century political rulers (in Palestine and Emperors), etc. I supplement this with dates from Carson and Moo's NT Intro, since they provide an alternate viewpoint. And then, of course, I turn to my own dates for Matthew and Mark, which I've pressed elsewhere.

I like the Karl-Heinz Vanheiden book Bibel-Chronik (in German).
Chapter 5 of this book depicts the chronology of the early Church. You can also find cross-references to the history of the Roman Empire.
But the book is in German, so it is not very helpful for all readers. Please excuse.
